# Delete UITextView text

Tags: text, uitextview

There is a reason why this method doesn't work?

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    textView.text = @"";
}
```

I just want that when I tap on UITextView, the text inside is canceled...

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REPLACE:**

OK.  Here is what you need to do.  First, in your class add the protocol:

```
@interface ClrssEditSearchVC : UITableViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

Then go into Interface Builder/Storyboard and Ctrl-drag from the `UITextView` to the source file and it will give you the option to create the event.  Then add your code to the new method.

**ADD:**

Another thing with your current implementation.  First, correction in terms.  You are working with a UITextField (not UITextView).  To get your original impl working:

First, be sure you you have added the protocol to your class.

```
@interface YourVC : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

Second, in your `viewDidLoad` method, add the following:

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Finally, your method sig needs to change to ("view" -> "field"):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: The textView is not nil, but the problem is that this method is never called!

Comment: @mutexmark, where did you implement this method?  Did you derive a new class from UITextView and implement it there?

Comment: No, I just implement this method in the UIViewController wich contains the UITextView

Comment: So, reading your answer I found the error. I totally forgot tu write "self.textView.delegate = self". Now that I write it in my viewDidLoad it works perfectly! Thanks!!